# Are Swift dictionaries automatically sorted?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have these two dictionaries:

```
let test = ["Tomorrow": "Bla", "Month": "Bla"]
print(test) // ["Tuesday": "Bla", "Month": "Bla"]

let test1 = ["Tomorrow": "Bla", "One Month": "Bla"]
print(test2) // ["One Month": "Bla", "Tuesday": "Bla"]
```

It seems that if i use the keyword "One" the element gets placed in front. Why?

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered, the order you *see* has **absolutely no meaning**..

Comment: It's been asked a thousand times already, please research before asking. Dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: @luk2302 and @EricD - you both should be more specific. Actually, there are _ordered_ associative containers and _unordered_ associative containers. It's just the internal implementation (via hash tables) that makes Swift's `Dictionary` and Objective-C `NSDictionary` an unordered container.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper no, we do not have to be more specific - we are talking about swift dictionaries here, not dictionaries in general. And the fact that the question has been asked thousand of times before does not really increase the will to be any more specific.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift's `Dictionary` is a hash-based data structure. Unless a specific ordering mechanism is in place, the order of items in hash-based structures depends on several factors:

- **Hash values of objects used as keys** - `hashValue` method is used to determine the bucket number for the item
- **Size of the structure** - Since `hashValue` can be much larger than the number of buckets available, a limiting mechanism, such as modulo bucket count, is used to decide the actual bucket number
- **Modification order** - this becomes relevant when keys have collisions. Elements with duplicate hash value placed later would either go to a different bucket, or be placed in a list associated with the actual bucket.

For example, if you change the size of dictionary in your second example, the order of items would reverse:

```
var test1 = [String:String]() // Use default initial capacity
test1["Tomorrow"] = "Bla"
test1["One Month"] = "Bla"
print(test1) // ["One Month": "Bla", "Tomorrow": "Bla"]

var test2 = [String:String](minimumCapacity: 11) // Use specific capacity
test2["Tomorrow"] = "Bla"
test2["One Month"] = "Bla"
print(test2) // ["Tomorrow": "Bla", "One Month": "Bla"]
```

Since some of these parameters are outside your control, the order of items in a `Dictionary` can be considered arbitrary for all practical purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!