# How to append elements into dictionary at specific index swift

Tags: swift

Hey Im trying to basically have the ability to put a new index first or last in the dictionary.

What Iv'e been able to mock up so far
Code:

```
 // no success

 var updatedList = [String: AnyObject]()

 updatedList.updateValue(child as AnyObject, forKey: "0")

 or 

 updatedList[child]


 to simply get child in array, I'm trying to figure out how to put it last or first in the dictionary
```

Comment: you are adding child as value and next line show you want to use the value as key???

Comment: It dosen't , make sence

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37295264/335858)

Comment: no thats just showing how I'm adding the child to the dictionary. But I'm trying to figure out how to add the child at the first or last index specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `Dictionary` as it has no sorting criteria , only you can add element for a key , this way can be in `Array` only